# What input file format could I use to create an equation?

Tags: java, c++, excel, input, vba

I'm using a surveillance software to find articles on specific topics based on a lot of web sources and equations. The equations ressemble the following :

```
(K1 AND K2) OR K3 NOT "K4" OR "K5 K6"~5
```

Exemple above illustrates almost every possible operator, ~ being the proximity operator, request match when the two words are found and separated by at most n words.

To give you a more precise example (? is a one character wildcard ; * is any number of characters)

```
("Game of Thrones" OR "George R. R. Martin") AND (Targaryen? OR Baratheon? NOT Lannister? OR "mother dragon?"~5)
```

---

What I would like to do is provide a script or program which would take the keywords and form the equation, without having to write all the parentheses. I think this would provide easier comparison between two equations and decrease error rate.

I first thought of an excel worksheet with a default "OR" operator :

```
keyword | logical operator | depth of parentheses
```

But that didn't work in every combination -- the program can't guess when the depth is constant between two lines when, in reality, it does -1 +1

I would like an **input** that is the easiest possible because I will probably send it to an average user. Do you have any idea ? I could then do the interpreter in C++, Java or even VBA.

**EDIT** / To clarify, I'm looking for an input format that would allow the end users not to write parentheses and to only care about their keywords and the relationship between them.

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for, is to match a String input against a given pattern. This a very common problem in CS that is well adressed by the concept of [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)  commonly called regexps.

However regexps are not that trivial to write, especially for newcomers. Even experienced programmers have sometimes difficulties to write the exact regexp they want.

There is a useful website to generate regexp [here](http://txt2re.com/). It needs some time to understand how it works, it is however an incredible time saver afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already quite fluent in regexp ;) Seeing your three answers, I think my question was not clearly stated. I'm looking for an input format that would allow the user not to write parentheses.

Comment: I think you should provide a graphical interface for the end user to build its query. In this case you really won't care about the input format, which in any will remain quite complicated (you will always require parentheses for complex boolean expressions)

Answer (score 1):

I think those parentheses can't be done properly all the time with Regexp.

As I remember from university, we learnt [Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) and [Formal Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language).

You will need to define allowed words in your language and some rules, to be a valid syntax( eg: parentheses must be closed, must be a word followed by a logical operator and so on) and finally you will have the execution result.

At execution it need to build a stack with those parentheses. And put values, and peek one.

I hope it helps, and you got a few keyword where to search it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see your point, though it only addresses the error rate problem, not the ease of use.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a scanner and a parser.

Writing a scanner and a parser yourself is not that hard. You can make a simple **RECURSIVE DESCENT PARSER** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) in a hundred lines.

However you can also use a compiler-compiler (like lex/yacc) tool to generate a parser from given grammar.